# load image in background and show loading page

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to load a layout (mostly images) in the background with `cached_network_image` in flutter.

I used [Splashscreen](https://github.com/ossolution/SplashScreenFlutterPackage) and this code, but it's not working. Do you have any ideas or maybe a better solution?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:login/packages/intro_slider.dart';
import 'package:login/packages/splashscreen.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestPage();
}

class _TestPage extends State<TestPage>{
  List<Slide> slides = new List();

  String pageOne = "";
  String pageTwo = "";

  getData() async{
    var userName = "";

    final response =
    await http.post('http://test.com/api',body: {"something":userName});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If server returns an OK response, Return pinCode
        var js = jsonDecode(response.body);
        pageOne = js[0]['pic1'].toString();
        pageTwo = js[0]['pic2'].toString();
        slides.add(
          new Slide(
            backgroundImage: "https://test.com/pic/" + pageOne,
            backgroundOpacity: 0,
          ),
        );
        slides.add(
          new Slide(
            backgroundImage: "https://test.com/pic/" + pageTwo,
            backgroundOpacity: 0,
          ),
        );

        return await new Future<Widget>.delayed(
            new Duration(
                seconds: 1
            ), () => slider()
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget slider(){
    return Scaffold(
      body: new IntroSlider(
        slides: this.slides,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      loadingData: getData,
      image: new Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
    );
  }
}
```

And, I try to cached image in `intro_slider`:

```
  PinchZoomImage(
    image: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: backgroundImage,
    ),
    hideStatusBarWhileZooming: true,
  ),
```